# How to reuse code inside a Expression<Func< ... >>?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm new to expressions and I'm playing around with them.

Having this expression for use in Linq to Entities `context.Products.Select(AsProductDto)`:

```
internal static readonly Expression<Func<Product, ProductDto>> 
    AsProductDto = product => new ProductDto 
    {
       // repeated code 
       Name = product.name 
       // ...
    };
```

I also want to have this constructor :

```
public class ProductDto {
    public ProductDto() { }
    public ProductDto(Product product) 
    {
       // repeated code 
       Name = product.name 
       // ...
    }
}
```

because of parameterless constructors requirement in Linq to Entities I cannot use

```
internal static readonly Expression<Func<Product, ProductDto>> 
        AsProductDto = product => new ProductDto(product)
```

Is there anyway I can reuse (aka not repeat) the portion of the code marked as repeated ?

Comment: "because of parameterless constructors requirement in Linq to Entities I cannot use ..." Why not? Although you must have a parameterless ctr, you can use the other one in your expression as well.

Comment: @Bart, you can't do what you want.  Linq-To-Entities works with object initializers, not constructors.  What is so wrong with your first attempt where you set the `Name` in your expression?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ....

Comment: @KirkWoll there's nothing wrong with it, I just don't want to dupe that code in other places.

Comment: @KirkWoll i guess the question is: how to reuse object initializers :D

Comment: You can't share member initialization code between initialization and calls in constructor/method because there is no such syntax in C# (I think you essentially want C preprocessor macros to be expanded into different syntactical constructs which *happen to have* exactly the same textual representation)...

Comment: @Bart, but really, what code are you *duplicating*?  `Name = product.Name` vs. `product.Name`?  You can't make the optimization you want.  Make peace with object initializers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the purpose of removing some duplicate you may perhaps introduce a setter for the `Product` in `ProductDto` class

this approach may help you reduce most of your duplicated lines,

this will be beneficial only when you have a couple of lines duplicated eg. copying a couple of properties of the product.

example

```
    internal static readonly Expression<Func<Product, ProductDto>>
        AsProductDto = product => new ProductDto
        {
            // single line call to setter
            Product = product
        };

    public class ProductDto
    {
        public ProductDto() { }
        public ProductDto(Product product)
        {
            // single line call to setter
            Product = product;
        }
        public ProductDto Product
        {
            set
            {
                // no more repeated code 
                Name = value.name;
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is an answer for exactly I was asking and I will accept as the correct answer. But I think it's too *clever* to actually implement in real code.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a function where you add products to the object and you can call it from anywhere you would like.

```
public class ProductDto {
    public ProductDto() { }
    public ProductDto(Product product) 
    {
        AddProduct(product)
    }
    public AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        Name = product.name
    }
}
```

Same applies to the above code

Comment: I don't think this will help with Linq-To-Entities SQL translation.