# WPF change properties simultaneously while window resizing

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, properties, window-resize

I have WPF window without borders (`WindowStyle == None`) and following code for manual form maximizing/restoration:

```cs
var currentScreen = this.CurrentScreen();
if (windowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Normal)
{
    windowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
    left = Left;
    top = Top;
    width = Width;
    height = Height;
    Left = currentScreen.WorkingArea.Left;
    Top = currentScreen.WorkingArea.Top;
    Width = currentScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
    Height = currentScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
}
else
{
    windowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
    Left = left;
    Top = top;
    Width = width;
    Height = height;
}
```

But size changing performs in several step: left position change, top position change, width change and height change. How can I change all of these properties simultaniously?

Comment: possibly use of updatelayout() at the end might help.

Comment: you may create a wrapper property as there is no such direct method, this will help you to reduce the number of lines if that is repeated a couple of time. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900598/how-to-reuse-code-inside-a-expressionfunc/24900766#24900766 for an example

Comment: "size changing performs in several steps". Are you really visually perceiving that your window updates these properties step by step?

Comment: +1. I'm currently encountering this problem. I'm changing the window from having no border to having a border (from ResizeMode == NoResize to ResizeMode = CanResize). This causes the rendered width and height to decrease, so I am compensating for that by adjusting the Left, Right, Width, and Height properties to preserve the rendered window size while adding the resizing borders. This causes the window to flicker as it gets redrawn after changing the resize mode and then again after adjusting the position and size. It would be great to know if it's possible to defer resizing or rendering.